# missing "<" while reading xml from a text file

Tags: java, regex, xml

I wrote a code to read multiple xml in one text file.

My text file looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
 <ns2: abc>
  <type>fruit</type>
 </abc>
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
 <ns2: abc>
  <type>cap</type>
 </abc>
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
 <ns2: abc>
  <type>veggie</type>
 </abc>
```

my java code to read and display them as three different xml files:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  File xmlFile=new File(location of .txt);
  Reader fileReader = new FileReader(xmlFile);
  BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line = bufReader.redLine();
  while( lin != null){
    sb.append(line).append("\n")
    line = bufReader.readLin();

    }

   String xml2 = sb.toString();
   final Pattern pattern =Pattern.compile("<?xml(.+?)</abc>", Pattern.DOTALL);
   final Matchr matcher = pattern.matcher(xml2);

    while(matcher.find()){
     Srting content = matcher.group(0);
     System.out.println(content);
      System.out.println("***************************");
    }
```

Th issue is- it is printing message like below:

```
  ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
  <ns2: abc>
  <type>fruit</type>
  </abc>
```

I am not getting "<" in front.

one more question - is there any better way of doing it rather than pattern matching?
for my requirement, the content of xml doesn't make any difference. I just want to get this output

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
    <ns2: abc>
    <type>fruit</type>
    </abc>
    *************************
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
    <ns2: abc>
    <type>cap</type>
    </abc>
    *************************
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
    <ns2: abc>
    <type>cap</type>
    </abc>
    ************************
```

Comment: Do you need to handle ANY well-formed XML? Even well-formed XML containing deliberately nasty things like commented-out XML declarations?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
final Pattern pattern =Pattern.compile("<?xml(.+?)</abc>", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

to

```
final Pattern pattern =Pattern.compile("<\?xml(.+?)</abc>", Pattern.DOTALL);
                                         ^
```

so that the `?` is literal rather than designating optionality of the `<`.